# How to set up wordpress domain mapping on MAMP Pro

Tags: multisite, localhost, domain-mapping

I am trying to set up a wordpress multisite with MAMP Pro that will allow me to have two different domains (one domain for each language):

dev.domainenglish.com
dev.domainfrench.com

I have already set up the primary english virtual host and secondary virtual french host. I have installed the wordpress multi site on the primary English virtual host. Next I created a "sub site" within the primary english domain multi site that has the location  dev.domainenglish.com/french/

Then I tried to use the MU Domain mapping plugin to make it so that when you visit dev.domainfrench.com the theme and content posted on dev.domainenglish.com/french/ will be visible.

As of now when you visit dev.domainfrench.com the page loads the standard MAMP Pro index.html instead of my wordpress subsite:

> the virtual host was set up successfully.
>
> If you can see this page, your new virtual host was set up successfully. Now, >web contents can be added and this placeholder page1 should be replaced or >deleted."

I understand that this plugin was built for live sites. But is there anyway I can achieve my goal of having two domains under one Wordpress multisite on my localhost?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

1. Install multi-site as subdomain setup. Do not use the sub-sites option.
2. Go to **Network Admin/Sites** and select the site whose URL you want to change:

   [image: screenshot]
3. Change the URL to the new domain.
4. In your `wp-config.php` use `define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );` to be able to log in in both sites.

You don't need a plugin for that.