# same wordpress, 2 domains

Tags: content, mobile, screen-layout

I currently have 2 domain names. www.xclo.co.uk is my site hosted by wordpress (found here www.xclo.co.uk/dir) and also www.xclo.mobi obviously for my mobile site.

now my .mobi site is pointed to .co.uk/mobile which has seperate layour and look to the .co.uk site.

What I was wondering is: is it possible to add the .mobi version to my dashboard and affectively run both .co.uk and .mobi on the one wordpress? As the content on .mobi will be different to that of .co.uk I feel as though this is the best option.

please can someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to run multiple sites from one installation:

1. Use multi-site with a subdomain setup. You can [use completely different domains](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94619/73) then.
2. [Adjust the site URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/96684/73) depending on the currently requested host.

Comment: they need to display 2 completely different layouts and 2 separate child themes though. Will this be possible with ether of the above methods?

Comment: Then use the first option: multi-site.

Comment: hmm. will this mean logging out of one and on to another? and not displaying both on one dashboard have one dashboard tab to display at .co.uk and the second at .co.uk/mobile.

Comment: You log in to both with the same credentials. Set up a test installation, and try it.