# Multisite install w/ Sub domains on a subdomain

Tags: multisite, htaccess, subdomains

I have a Wordpress installation which I have installed on a subdomain `login.mysite.com`. I would like to create additional sites that use the same application on `feed.mysite.com`, but technically this isn't allowed. Because the main installation happened on a subdomain, it forces me to use:

`feed.login.mysite.com`

Is there a way to get around this, or within my server can I point the sub-sub-domain to a sub-domain?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There are really nice plugins for this kind of Multisite Domain Mapping: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Comment: That's great. Hoping to do it manually however.

Comment: Have you tried to [enter the new domains directly](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94619/73)?